# Like to conditionally render an initialValue in formik

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, render, formik

I'm having trouble understanding Formik and conditionally rendering some of the items
Like to conditionally render an initial value in formik keep telling me that image is undefined when in the if statement

```
<Formik
                enableReinitialize={true}

                

                initialValues={{
                    
                    name: currentBankData.name || '',
                    address: currentBankData.address || '',
                    country: currentBankData.country || '',
                    region: currentBankData.region || '',
                    city: currentBankData.city || '',
                    swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
                    routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
                    
                    
                
        
                    image: currentBankData.image || ''

            
                    
                    /*Something Like this
                    baniId ? (
                    image: currentBankData.image || ''   
                    ) : ("")
                    */
                    



                }   

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? If `baniId` then `currentBankData.image` otherwise `''`

```
initialValues={{
    // ...
    image: baniId ? currentBankData.image : ''
    // ...
 }}
```